# AS3 Button that works for all Scene/Frame (Flash CS6)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, button

Alright, I have a difficult problem "for me" , I'm a beginner in Adobe Flash CS6.

**The Problem**

I can't make the button works for all frame. I was unable to click once I jump to another frame or scene.

**The Explaination**

I'll explain more detail what I'm trying to do with the button.

1. I Have have a button which is named "Back to Menu" that placed in "Play" Scene, the button supposed to get the user back to the menu.

   - "Main Menu" Scene (1 Frame)
   - "Play" Scene (10 Frame)
2. The code is placed on frame 1, in the "Play" Scene and the code used is :

```js
backtomenu.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, backmenuClick);
 
function backmenuClick(ev:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoandPlay ("Main Menu");
}
```

3. So, at the Main Menu there is 9 button, each button from the "Main Menu" Scene will bring to the different frame at the "Play" Scene. The backtomenu button works fine when I click the button that take me to the frame 1 in "Play Scene", but whenever I click the button that direct me from "Main Menu" Scene to frame 2 , 3 or 4 in "Play" Scene, the backtomenu button won't work.

Is there any other way to make the code readable to all frame? or make a universal button? Because I know the code wasn't read when I was at the 2nd Frame in the "Play" Scene. do I have to make a different code for each frame? if that so, that's insane.

Comment: Drop scenes, or nest your MCs so that the button exists outside the MC that's changing scenes. Also you can add a second MC on top of that MC you use for scenes, and add that button there. Make sure however that the second MC is added to `stage` and not first MC.

Comment: how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can put your "Back to Menu" button on a new layer with 1 keyframe & 9 frames to cover the whole "Play" scene.
Your "backtomenu.addEventListener" code needs to be placed in the keyframe of the new layer.